# jQuery hide/show DIV function not working

Tags: jquery

I'm loading data via AJAX/jQuery using an API. I want one div to show and the other to hide when I click the button, but I'm not able to get that working with the code I have, any ideas?

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".groups").show("");
  });
  $(".matches").hide("");
});
```

```css
.groups {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<div class="groups">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<div class="matches">
  <p>test 2</p>
</div>
```

Obviously, for this I've taken out the AJAX/jQuery for simplicity, but the data would be loaded into the div's provided.

Comment: Move the `hide()` call inside the `click` handler function

Comment: The edit has damaged this question - the JS is NOT the same in the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the jQuery [`toggle`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function, which toggles the visibility of elements (*i.e.* it shows the hidden elements and hides the visible ones).

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".groups, .matches").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.groups {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<div class="groups">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<div class="matches">
  <p>test 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle between two classes like below to show / hide div.

```js
$('button').on(
  'click',
  function() {
    $('div').toggleClass('groups','matches')
  }
);
```

```css
.groups {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<div class="groups">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<div class="matches">
  <p>test 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the console, it will tell you what's wrong. The syntax you're using for the `click` handler is incorrect.

It should be as follows:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    $(".groups").show();
    $(".matches").hide();
});
```

```css
.groups {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click me</button>

<div class="groups"><p>test</p></div>
<div class="matches"><p>test 2</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra }); where it's not needed.

This code works: https://jsfiddle.net/tyddlywink/g65e3sc0/

New Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".groups").show("");
    $(".matches").hide("");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code.

If you create the div on the fly, then you need ensure that the click event handler will target the new elements, so you need to use $(document)...
Which you will need if you (and should) target these using a class.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    $(".groups").show("");
$(".matches").hide("");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.groups {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<div class="groups">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<div class="matches">
  <p>test 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toggle()` to show one div and then the other each time you click like so. Make sure to include both `.toggle()` methods in your `.click` callback method:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".groups").toggle();
  $(".matches").toggle();
});
```

```css
.groups {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<div class="groups">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<div class="matches">
  <p>test 2</p>
</div>
```